# MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Send not working on linux

Tags: linux, ssl, smtpclient, mailkit

The following code written in the .net core 2, works in the windows environment but not in the linux.and the port 25 works in linux,but the port 465 not work in linux.

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MimeKit;
using System;

public class MailTest
{
    public static void Send()
    {
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("from", "from@xx.cn"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("me", "me@xx.cn"));
    message.Subject = string.Format("mailtest {0}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = "I want to send a ssl mail" };
    try
    {
        var client = new SmtpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("new SmtpClient()");
        // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
        Console.WriteLine(client.SslProtocols);

        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------\n");
            return true;
        };

        Console.WriteLine("begin Connect");
        client.Connect("smtp.exmail.qq.com", 465, true);
        Console.WriteLine("end Connect");

        // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
        // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

        Console.WriteLine("Encoding.Default:{0}", System.Text.Encoding.Default.BodyName);
        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate("from@mallcoo.cn", "xxxxxx");

        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);

        client.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ex:{0}", ex);
    }
    }
}
```

It throw exception at client.Connect("smtp.exmail.qq.com", 465, true); There seems to be no calling to client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback. the log below:

```
new SmtpClient()
Tls, Tls11, Tls12
begin Connect
ex:System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.MapVerifyErrorToChainStatus(X509VerifyStatusCode code)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.AddElementStatus(X509VerifyStatusCode errorCode, List`1 elementStatus, List`1 overallStatus)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.AddElementStatus(List`1 errorCodes, List`1 elementStatus, List`1 overallStatus)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.BuildChain(X509Certificate2 leaf, HashSet`1 candidates, HashSet`1 systemTrusted, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan& remainingDownloadTime)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean throwOnException)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at System.Net.Security.CertificateValidation.BuildChainAndVerifyProperties(X509Chain chain, X509Certificate2 remoteCertificate, Boolean checkCertName, String hostName)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.MailService.Connect(String host, Int32 port, Boolean useSsl, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Tom.MailTest.Send() in C:\git\Tom\src\Tom\MailTest.cs:line 45
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in DotNet Core CLR as the error is happening within the CoreCLR's OpenSSL portability abstraction layer (that's what PAL is).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in DotNet Core CLR as the error is happening within the CoreCLR's OpenSSL portability abstraction layer (that's what PAL is).

I would recommend submitting a bug report to https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues